# How do I change the XmlElement name dynamically?

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

```
[XmlRoot("A")]
public class Foos
{
   [XmlElement("A1")]
   public List<Foo> FooList{ get; set; }
}


var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foos));
```

This code working as well. But its not dynamic. I want `[XmlRoot("A")]` to `[XmlRoot(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[someValue])]`. But is throw to syntax error. Then i try this

```
    public class Foos
    {
       [XmlElement("A1")]
       public List<Foo> FooList{ get; set; }
    }
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foos),new XmlRootAttribute(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[someValue]));
```

This is work just root element.I'm working. I could not change the "XmlElement" value of the FooList dynamically.There can be more than one element in the class. How do I change the XmlElement value of all of them dynamically?

Comment: @BassemAkl is just for Root element. I Wrote this. "This is work just root element". But i want for inner class elements.

Comment: My mistake. I took my comment down.

Comment: I found this article to be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlroot?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use XmlAttributesOverrides in a right way. [Please Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244486/how-to-use-xmlattributeoverrides-when-serializing-an-array).

Working version of your code is here.

```
public class Foos
{       
    public List<Foo> FooList { get; set; }
}


public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var xmlAttributeForFoos = new XmlAttributes { XmlRoot = new XmlRootAttribute(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someFoosValue"]), XmlType = new XmlTypeAttribute(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someFoosValue"]) };
        var xmlAttributeForFooList = new XmlAttributes();
        var xmlAttributeForFoo = new XmlAttributes();

        xmlAttributeForFooList.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someFooValue"]));
        xmlAttributeForFoo.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someFooNameValue"]));

         var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        overrides.Add(typeof(Foos), xmlAttributeForFoos);
        overrides.Add(typeof(Foos), "FooList", xmlAttributeForFooList);
        overrides.Add(typeof(Foo), "Name", xmlAttributeForFoo);

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foos), overrides);

        var foos = new Foos
        {
            FooList = new List<Foo>
            {
                new Foo{Name = "FooName"}
            }
        };

        using (var stream = File.Open("file.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stream, foos);
        }
    }
}
```

App settings

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="someFoosValue" value="SomeFoos"/>    
  <add key="someFooValue" value="SomeFoo"/>
  <add key="someFooNameValue" value="FooName"/>
</appSettings>
```

output

```
<SomeFoos xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SomeFoo>
    <FooName>FooName</FooName>
  </SomeFoo>
</SomeFoos>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL, I changed the code what you want exactly. I guess that you already found the solution but it' s better to keep like that.

Comment: Last question :). If i want  add `[XmlElement(someValue)]` `public string Name { get; set; }` dynamic is possible? @nmkaya

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL, I updated the code, please check.